# After adding mui icon material I get an invalid hook call, I tried looking for ways to solve this problem but I couldnt understand any

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, icons

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Contact.css';
import './ThePhoneBook';
import InfoIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Info';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';

function Contact(props) {
  return (
    <div class="contact">
      <div class="contactDetails">
        <div class="contactImageContainer">
          <img class="contactProfilePic" src={props.data.image} alt='' />
        </div>
        <div class="contactNameContainer">
          <p class="contactP">{props.data.name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <span
        class="updateButton"
        onClick={() => props.callback.updateCurrentContact(props.data.id, 1)}
      >
      <EditIcon fontSize="large" />
      </span>
      <span
        class="infoButton"
        onClick={() => props.callback.updateCurrentContact(props.data.id, 2)}
      >
        <InfoIcon fontSize="large" />
      </span>
      <span
        class="deleteButton"
        onClick={() => props.callback.deleteContact(props.data)}
      >
        &#10060;
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

Everything works perfectly when I hide the info and edit icon along with their imports. And on the console on google chrome I get this error message "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." I am not sure what I am supposed to do exactly to make this work.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "final-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[The error message with the blank page. I can't see any of my content because of the invalid hook call. Also ignore the warning messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb6ve.png)

Comment: You're trying to create ui library ? which bundle do you use webpack or rollup ?

Comment: I am not, I am trying to just add these two icons, I followed the instructions on https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/ I imported them the way it says to but I cant see anything in my project after adding these two. all I get is a blank page with the error message I mentioned above.

Comment: This error message is because there is two different versiosn of react js in your project, usually this error when using npm link for a local ui library , it's not your case, please try to share your package.json

Comment: I have edited my question and added it.

Comment: try the solution below , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your react and react-dom versions are > 17.0.0 , they said that it's added as a peerDependencies but it's cause a problem , i suggest to downgrade your react & react-dom versions
try to use this package.json
and then : npm install or yarn install

```js
{
  "name": "final-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It still didn't work. I have added them and nothing changed. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Vani i changed the answer please re-read it again and downgrade your react versions
i don't see mui installed you need to add -D when installing it to be saved in your package.json

Comment: I tried, it still doesn't show in the package.json for some reason.

Comment: if you use npm : npm install --save @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
We need to know weach version of mui you use

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't show when I try that. I am gonna look for the latest version and try to add it manually to the package.json and see if it helps.

Comment: okey before that , try to delete your package.lock.json and node-modules and try again with the command with --save

Comment: It still didn't add them. I even tried closing and opening again and retrying. It won't add. I don't know why.

Comment: it's well installed ? , i mean in  your console after typing the command

Comment: Nothing is working because of the icons. I could replace them with buttons but I must have the icons. I don't know what to do...

Comment: you're succesffully installed the mui ?? i means it appears now in your package.json ?
As i mentionned before the problem is the versiosn are not compatible you need to downgrade react based on the mui versions

Comment: It does not appear in my package.json. No matter what I do it just doesn't show there.

Comment: you need to fix that i think it's the cause of your problem, may be mui not proerly installed? what is your npm installed versions

Comment: I removed it and used react icons. React icons worked successfully. I appreciate how you tried to help me.